# Cors rails - Parameters are not send in POST method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, cors, fetch

In a Rails API, I have a `login` POST method in my `UsersController` which takes 2 parameters (mail and password) and check in DB if a record is found and if so returns it.

```
  def login(mail, password)
    user = User.where(mail: mail, password: password)
    render json: user
  end
```

In my front side, in React, I call this method with `fetch` which takes the mail and password values in a form:

```
  login = () => {
    if(this.state.mail != null && this.state.password != null){
        fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3001/api/login', {
            method: 'post',
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                            mail: this.state.mail,
                            password: this.state.password
                        }),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res)
            if(res.data.length === 1 ){
                const cookies = new Cookies();
                cookies.set('mercato-cookie',res.data[0].id,{path: '/'});
                this.setState({redirect: true})
            }
        })
    }
  }
```

The method is well called, but I have the following error : `ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 2))`, I tried it with Postman with the same result so I guess the problem is a Rails one.
Here is my cors configuration :

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3000'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: :true
  end
end
```

I thought the `credentials: :true` would resolve the problem but it does not.
I'm out of ideas here :/

Comment: see @Ursus's answer below, but is there a reason you're saving your users' password in the raw form?

Comment: Yes, it's intentional to have a non secure form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails' actions do not handle parameters in that way. You have to use `params`.

```
def login(mail, password)
  user = User.where(mail: mail, password: password)
  render json: user
end
```

to

```
def login
  mail, password = params.values_at(:mail, :password)
  user = User.where(mail: mail, password: password)
  render json: user
end
```